# How to attach hose to router table port?

Tags: powertools, routers, dust

How do I attach my dust collection hose to the port on router table fence?  I am using a standard shop-vac hose.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you've provided no information about what actual size the shop vac hose (there are multiple "standards" though 2-1/4 inch is the one I'd usually assume) or the size of the hole in the router fence, either something like this, or something like that in the the other direction (or a chunk of wood with an appropriate size hole drilled in it.) The first can be cut to provide various smaller sizes or a flange, the second increases size to 4 inches.

Shop vac adapter (or Shop vac hose adapter) will get results in a search engine.

Or 1/3 of a roll of duct tape... ;-)

[image: shop-vac universal adapter image from amazon.]
[image: woodcraft 4" adapter]

Comment: Is it common practice to have to drill holes and attach an adapter or is this meant to accept a particular fitting that holds tight without fasteners?

Comment: They are usually just push-fit. When in use, the vacuum helps to hold them in position.

Comment: Very generic answer for a very generic question. Well done!